# Google sheet: How to automatically add all columns to graph series?

Tags: google-sheets, bar-chart, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have a pivot table with many columns.

I create a multi-bar chart graph with series of the columns.

1. How can I automatically set the range to be the active range of the whole table?
2. After choosing the whole range, only 6 series are added automatically.
   How can I select all available series to appear on the multi-bar graph?

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a sample spreadsheet? Additionally, describe how you are  currently creating the chart.